# Plannar Inductor Unacounted Parasitic Capacitance

Tags: inductor, pcb-fabrication, parasitic-capacitance

I'm trying to determine the source of approximately 300pf worth of parasitic capacitance in a planar coil project I'm working on. I'm trying to find out how my numerical predictions line up with the manufactured design. I've done an array of different sizes and, I see a shift in resonate frequency that corresponds to ~300pf across all of them

The example below has the following parameters 
Layers: 2
Trace Width: 0.205mm
Trace Spacing: 0.152mm
Number of Turns: 10
Inner Diameter: 5.08mm
Outer Diameter: 12.548mm
Board Thickness:  1.13mm
Self Inductance: 0.994uH
Total Inductance: 2.99uH
Parallel C: 1nF
Predicted Resonate Frequency (w/1nF C): 2.899MHz
Measured Resonate Frequency: 2.534MHz

I'm fairly confident in the predicted numbers as they match what the [TI Coil Designer](https://webench.ti.com/wb5/LDC/#/spirals) outputs If its to be trusted. Its the measured resonant frequency that's got me. I measured the frequency with a Rigol DS1054 in two ways

1. Apply a sine-wave swept across multiple frequencies and measured the input and output voltage.
2. Apply a 1Khz square wave and measure the output oscillations

I can account for 13pF from the scope input and 13pF from the probe input. Additionally, from [paper](http://sci-hub.tw/10.1049/el:20072513) I can approximate the capacitance between the two layers as the two plates of a donut-shaped capacitor, but at best, that only accounts for an additional ~13pF, for a total of 39pF.

There's no metal under the surface that would affect it, there is no ground place to couple to. I'm missing something, but I can't think of what it is.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq4cmG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What about interwinding capacitance? Meaning from adjacent traces in the coil?

Comment: page 83 of this paper https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj_loP_4_PrAhUNuZ4KHcimC4cQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fopen.library.ubc.ca%2Fcollections%2F24%2Fitems%2F1.0319259&usg=AOvVaw19K2FCFGiZoAl0Hb3QBLHq shows somthin like that, but I dont know how I could model that. And even then would that make up the remaining 200 ish pF?

Answer (score 1):

Using equation 2 from page 3 of this white paper on [distributed capacitance](http://www.datatronics.com/pdf/distributed_capacitance_paper.pdf)
It covers the 300pF you describe.

\$Cd=\LARGE\frac{(\frac{1}{2\pi(SFR)})^2}{L}\$

When \$SFR = 2.899MHz\$ Then \$Cd=1.005nF\$

At the predicted SFR, that is your 1nF parallel cap

When \$SFR = 2.534MHz\$ Then \$Cd=1.315nF\$

At the actual SFR freq there is an **additional 300pF!**

Comment: This to me, looks like its talking about coupled capacitance through transformers. Your right that Cd = 1.315pF at 2.3534Mhz but that's just rearranging the `$SRF = 1 / 2\pi \sqrt{LC}$` it dosen't tell when where the 300pf is coming from, unless I missed somthing.

Comment: @Lpaulson Yeah,looks like it's bundling all the cap effects together. *"**The voltage difference between turns**,
between winding layers and between windings to core create these parasitic elements."*

Comment: Hmm sounds reasonable, but feels anti-climatic.

Comment: @Lpaulson I still think it is the turn to turn capacitance, similar to the link you posted in your comment.